# Gradient background UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

How to add gradient background to UIScrollView? I have a viewcontroller with UIScrollView on top of it. I want to add gradient background to scrollview. I also have  a gradient image for background, but it is not completely fitting the content size of scroll view.

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I've previously set the `UIScrollView` `backgroundColor` to clear then positioned a gradient view behind the scroll view.  Then draw a gradient on that `UIView` like:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
    CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGGradientRef glossGradient;
    CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorspace;
    size_t num_locations = 2;
    CGFloat locations[2] = { 0.0, 1.0 };
    CGFloat components[8] = { 0.119, 0.164, 0.192, 1.000,  // Start color
        0.286, 0.300, 0.307, 1.000 }; // End color

    rgbColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    glossGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(rgbColorspace, components, locations, num_locations);

    CGRect currentBounds = self.bounds;
    CGPoint topCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(currentBounds), 0.0f);
    CGPoint midCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(currentBounds), CGRectGetMaxY(currentBounds));
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(currentContext, glossGradient, topCenter, midCenter, 0);

    CGGradientRelease(glossGradient);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorspace); 
}
```

I don't know what effect drawing a gradient directly in `UIScrollView`'s `drawRect` would have.

Answer (score 1):

Download sample project from https://github.com/techiedees/GradientTest link.

Its having TDGradientView framework in it. Just use it to any project you want.

You can check it at http://www.techiedees.com/2012/04/how-to-create-gradient-view-at-run-time.html